# Constraint layout not aligning textview

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

i am using contraint layout to align my textview in each corner of the screen but it looks like it is not working. the text on the right size of the screen gets align according to text length on the left size.  take a look at the attach pic. text on the right is not properly align. for some reason there are a few spaces off. how can fix that?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/payout_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="@string/payout_label"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/income_icon"/>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/income_icon"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-50dp"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_income"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="Salary"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/income_icon"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/income_icon"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/income_amount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="$0.00"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/green"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.91"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/category"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/income_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/frequency"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/grey"
        android:text="Monthly"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/income_icon"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/income_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pending"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        android:textColor="@color/grey"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/income_icon"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.91"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/frequency" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your mistakes are these - you must remove these

- this line in income_amount

  ```
  app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/category"
  ```
- this line in status

  ```
  app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/frequency"
  ```

this is correct design

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">


  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/payout_date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:text="payout_label"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/income_icon"/>


  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/income_icon"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-50dp"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/leak_canary_icon"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/category"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="Salary"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/income_amount"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/income_icon"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/income_icon"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/income_amount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="$0.00"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/green"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/income_icon"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/frequency"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="Monthly"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="@color/grey"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/income_icon"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/status"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/income_icon"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/status"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="Pending"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
    android:textColor="@color/grey"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/income_icon"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the amount to be right-justified and aligned, you don't need the following two lines of XML:

```
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.91"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/category"
```

So, just delete them to give the following:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/income_amount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="$0.00"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/green"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/income_icon" />
```

If you need a margin on the right of, say, `16dp`, add:

```
android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have aligned the status TextView to amount TextView and have given an 8 dp from right to status TextView so that it aligns to the amount TextView. Below is the code for it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/payout_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:text="payout_label"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/income_icon"/>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/income_icon"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-50dp"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:text="Salary"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/income_icon"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/income_icon"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/income_amount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="$0.00"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.91"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/category"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/income_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/frequency"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:text="Monthly"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/income_icon"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/income_icon"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="Pending"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/income_icon"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/income_amount"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/income_amount" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Hope that helps!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Design your layout like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/payout_date"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="payout_label"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/color_black"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/income_icon"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_inbox_active"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/payout_date"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/payout_date"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="30dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Salary"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/color_black"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/income_icon"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/income_amount"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/income_icon"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="61dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="34dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/income_amount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="$0.00"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/color_black"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/payout_date"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="344dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="30dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/frequency"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Monthly"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/category"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/category"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/status"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/color_black"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="61dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="59dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pending"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        android:textColor="@color/color_black"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/income_amount" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]